# Joining tables to find a SUM

Tags: sql, join

i need some help with this SQL Join..

I have a table "sales" , looking like this

```
date        idpart
1311316400   5
1321316400   6
1341216400   7
1351516400   8
```

and a table "parts" looking like this

```
idpart   name    inprice  outprice
 5        a        10       40
 6        b        20       55
 7        c        20       55 
 8        d        20       55
```

Now i want to find the sum of all partsales between a user given date A and date B , by doing something like this:

```
SELECT idpart, SUM( inprice ) 
FROM parts, sales
WHERE parts.idpart = sales.idpart
GROUP BY idpart
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But by doing this i get the value of inprice for each of the time a part is in sales table.
I want the total for the entire period between A and B.
I dont know where i should insert the :

```
WHERE date BETWEEN A AND B
```

any tips for a SQL beginner ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, then you can just combine your conditions using the keyword `AND`:

```
SELECT SUM( inprice ) 
FROM parts, sales
WHERE parts.idpart = sales.idpart
AND sales.date BETWEEN A AND B
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

For better readability always use the "new" `JOIN`-syntax. Once your queries become more complex, this makes it a lot easier to understand your queries:

```
SELECT SUM( parts.inprice ) 
FROM sales
JOIN parts ON ( parts.idpart = sales.idpart )
WHERE sales.date BETWEEN a AND b
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i still get the sum for each idpart in the sales table. I am trying to get the sum of inprice for all parts in total, for the given period :(

Comment: +1 for the advice to start using the "new" JOIN-syntax. The "old" one makes queries very unreadable, especially when they get larger!